# creating gin index in postgreqsql

Tags: indexing, postgresql-9.1

I am using "PostgreSQL 9.1.5",i am trying to create gin index for the text column.It is showing  error message.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    first_name text,
    last_name text
)


CREATE INDEX users_search_idx ON users USING gin (first_name,last_name)
```

I am having column values like this(first_name)

```
"456fc0470a95c02bb42ef3e35fc81852"
```

i am trying to query the data like this.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM users where first_name like '%aeb%'
```

Comment: Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: i made some changes in my original post.actually i am getting error message data type  "text has no default operator class for access method "gin" "

Comment: That is one strange first name ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to make use of a trigram search, you need to first install the [pg_trgm](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/pgtrgm.html) extension:

```
create extension pg_trgm;
```

(This needs to be done as the superuser)

Then you need to provide the operator class to be used in the index:

```
CREATE INDEX users_search_idx 
   ON users USING gin (first_name gin_trgm_ops, last_name gin_trgm_ops);
```

But a combined index on both columns would not support e.g. `where last_name like`%aeb%'`. If you need to search on the two column individually, you need two indexes.